# What Xamarin.iOS End of Life means for me

Tags: xamarin.ios

As a result of purchasing another startup, my company inherited an iOS app written in Xamarin.ios including storyboards in XCode. We have not made a release on this app in over the past year. We learned that Xamarin EOL is occurring in May, 2024 and we are trying to understand the implications. Our goal is to keep this app stable as long as possible so we can rewrite it completely.

We performed a short investigation to try and upgrade to a .NET SDK style project (as per the upgrade recommendations) but we ran into issues with multiple incompatible nuget packages and were unable to build. We are trying to understand the path before us and what the options are.

Here are my questions:

1. One major risk we are considering is that we don't know how well adopted and stable the newer version of .NET style iOS apps are. We don't know how many have successfully upgraded and what kind of issues we may encounter either performing the upgrade or subsequently once the app is live (eg: crashes, etc.). We have thousands of users using this app for their business operations so stability is key. Has anyone performed this upgrade successfully and what has been your experience?
2. What is the risk of doing nothing?
   a. While the app runs fine on iOS 17 and has run fine on previous versions as well with very few changes over the past few years, is there a probable chance that with each new iOS version we will encounter an incompatibility and be required to upgrade the app?
   b. As the app is still targeting iOS 10, is this likely to reduce the likelihood of compatibility issues? ie: does iOS recognize this and effectively run the app in a "backwards" compatible mode? Again, our goal is to buy time.

We appreciate any information that can help support our understanding.

As noted above, we tried to build a .NET style SDK project as outlined in the Xamarin.iOS end of life migration guide.  However, at this point we don't know how long a successful migration is likely to take, and also whether if it's feasible and/or if it could lead to production stability issues.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  This question isn't on topic for SO

Comment: A bunch of Xamarin developers have moved their native apps, what issues have you faced, this question is kind of, off topic for SO, But if you wanna discuss this personally I can

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify why?  This is not about a specific development problem, but about the technology stack itself.

Comment: SO is specifically for questions about "specific development problems".  Open ended discussions are not.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for clarifying and sorry for posting it here.